# Can I reduce lines with two similar groupby functions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have this code that works as expected with python3.

## 1

```
resumen = datos.groupby(['subid2']).agg(
    total_clicks = pd.NamedAgg('clicks', 'sum'),
    total_revenue = pd.NamedAgg('revenue', 'sum')
)
resumen['avg_cpc'] = resumen['total_revenue'] / resumen['total_clicks']
print(resumen)
```

## 2

```
words = datos.groupby(['subid2','keyword']).agg(
    total_clicks = pd.NamedAgg('clicks', 'sum'),
    total_revenue = pd.NamedAgg('revenue', 'sum')
)
words['avg_cpc'] = words['total_revenue'] / words['total_clicks']
print(words)
```

As you can see, #2 is almost exactly like #1 but just adding one element on groupby.

I tried changing #2 for:

```
words = resumen.groupby('keyword'])
print(words)
```

Thinking I could save some lines of code. Is it possible to do it somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would write a function with flexible arguments (give it a descriptive name, unlike below): [`by`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) follows the same restrictions as the argument in `groupby`.

```
def my_func(df, by):   
    res = df.groupby(by).agg(
            total_clicks = pd.NamedAgg('clicks', 'sum'),
            total_revenue = pd.NamedAgg('revenue', 'sum')
            )
    res['avg_cpc'] = res['total_revenue'] / res['total_clicks']
    return res
```

Then

```
print(my_func(datos, 'subid2'))
print(my_func(datos, ['subid2', 'keyword']))
```